# Base64 encode and image in Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, air, base64, xml-rpc

I am writing an Adobe Air app in HTML/JavaScript and I am trying to base64 encode an image so I can add it to and XML RPC request. I have tried many methods and nothing seems to work.

I see that actionscript has a Base64Encoder class that look like it would work, is there any way to utilize this in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @some for the link.

I used the btoa() function to base64 encode image data like this:

`var loader = new air.URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = air.URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE,function(e){ 
      var base64image = btoa(loader.data);
 });
var req = new air.URLRequest('file://your_path_here');
loader.load(req);`

I was trying to upload an image using metaWeblog.newMediaObject, but it turns out that the data doesn't need to be base64 encoded, so the binary value was all that was needed.